# How to work fun get(index: Int): Char?

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand how function work.
I write array[1]=str.get(1), when str ="123".
But compilier write me about error on funtion get. 
What i do wrong?

Comment: No effort in this question, whatsoever. Learn [ask] a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Could not reproduce: I execute `val array = CharArray(5);
val str = "123";
array[1] = str.get(1)` and get it work correctly. Please add details or examples.

Comment: Code:   var panCheckNumber= IntArray(9) ;  for (i in 1..9){panCheckNumber[i]=str.get(i) }  . I did mistake when use IntArray. Tnx.

Comment: A Char is not an Int in Kotlin

Comment: @ВикторГротов your question is still cryptic and hard to understand. I suggest reformatting the code (see how it was done in the answer) and providing types and declarations for all variables. This is necessary for others to understand your question and profit from the answers.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, you can store a `char` into an `int[]` without casting. In Kotlin, this is not possible, you will have to use the `toInt()` method:

```
val ints = IntArray(5)
val str = "123"
ints[1] = str.get(1).toInt()
```